# How to sort by multiple columns in Excel, using a macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I Need Something like This, thank you

[image]

And I will insert automatically values in the last column (it'll be auto increment values).

Comment: By filtering the range in discussion, by each column... Do it manually and record a macro. If you want a piece of code to do that, without filtering, it is not complicated, but we need to see what you tried on your own. You must prove a minimum involvement in solving the problem by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press record macro and then: Excel ribbon -> Data -> Sort -> Add levels and sort by colums and other criterias. Check the link with image.

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPeUw.png)

Comment: Thanks a lot man, but i need to do this with a macro, and insert (values) automatically in the last column.

Comment: that's how you create a macro - you record yourself doing it - have you never recorded your own macro?

Comment: @munirmounir you need to learn basic things. Excel has function - "Record macro". Then you press "on" it captures everything you do and writes VBA code in module. I showed you how to sort everything, and if you will do the same with "Record macro" you will get yur VBA code for free. Don't forget to press stop ;).